# Rails deployment with Capistrano failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, production

I'm pretty new to RoR and deploying apps like these into production, so I've been doing quite a bit of reading.

There's one problem I can't seem to get past however. During my investigation, I came upon a thread on SO that indicates the behavior of Capistrano v3.x changed, which has confused some people.

One thing the thread detailed to do, was implement a remote file check, and if it doesn't exist during deployment, declare the local file to upload (which is my interpretation).

The following was added into my config/deploy.rb:

```
namespace :deploy do
  namespace :check do
    task :linked_files => 'config/database.yml'
  end
  remote_file 'config/database.yml' => '/home/ubuntu/workspace/config/database.yml'
...
end
```

I'm working within Cloud9 IDE. When I run the `cap production deploy` command, the following excerpt from the deployment log is returned:

```
INFO [5cccd59b] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /home/deploy/--------/shared/config as deploy@---------------.com
DEBUG [5cccd59b] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /home/deploy/--------/shared/config
INFO [5cccd59b] Finished in 0.068 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [bd9797ee] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /home/deploy/--------/shared/deploy:config/database.yml ] as deploy@---------------.com
DEBUG [bd9797ee] Command: [ -f /home/deploy/--------/shared/deploy:config/database.yml ]
DEBUG [bd9797ee] Finished in 0.067 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
INFO Uploading /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/database.yml to /home/deploy/--------/shared/deploy:config/database.yml
DEBUG Uploading /home/deploy/--------/shared/deploy:config/database.yml 0.0%
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@---------------.com: scp: /home/deploy/--------/shared/deploy:config/database.yml: No such file or directory
```

I don't know 100%, but it seems to me that the path that it's auto inserting with the : is throwing off the script.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Gabrial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `remote_file` without any namespaces.

```
namespace :deploy do
  namespace :check do
    task :linked_files => 'config/database.yml'
  end
...
end

remote_file 'config/database.yml' => '/home/ubuntu/workspace/config/database.yml'
```

Comment: Thanks! that's what it was. Although now there's a new issue to investigate, I'm further along. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a database.yml file in your shared directory. Also, it's worth noting that if you've been working in a development environment, you'll have to configure the database.yml file for production as well. Check to make sure *yml isn't listed in your .gitignore file.

Here's an example production entry:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: production_for_my_app
  username: root
  password: ''
  host: localhost
```

Although you may have a database.yml file checked into version control, you need to have one in the shared directory outside of the app in your case.

To do this, SSH into your box

```
cd /home/rails/< your app >/shared/config
```

Then make the database.yml file

```
touch database.yml

nano database.yml
```

Then copy and paste the contents of the copy of database.yml that you have in version control into the database.yml file you just created.

Save the file and you're in business.

Comment: From my config/database.yml file which exists in the remote repository (ie not included in the .gitignore file)

production:  
  adapter: mysql2  
  hostname: localhost  
  username: deploy  
  password: '----------'  
  database: production

Comment: The issue is most certainly something to do with that file. Could even be indentation.

Comment: The comment thing strips the formatting, but what is in my database.yml matches what you listed, with of course changes to the relevant bits

Comment: See my edit. You need to copy the database.yml file to your shared directory.

Comment: Doesn't work. The Capistrano deployment script detects that the remote file does not exist, and so attempts to upload it. It fails I believe because the script is inserting a colon into the remote file path instead of a forward slash.

It fails because path/to:dir/file is an invalid file path.